# Seleccionar de un diccionario la lista con menos elementos

Tags: c#, diccionarios

Tengo un `concurrentDictionary` en el que contiene una lista. Me gustaria saber como puedo obtener la Key de la lista con menos elementos.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<object>> _listInfo = null;
```

Por ejemplo , imaginar que el diccionario contiene 4 registros con los siguientes valores:

```
key(string) | lista(object)
    1          1,2,3,4
    2          1
    3          1,2,3,4,5
    4          1,2
```

La idea es hacer una consulta sobre el diccionario y que devuelva la Key 2 que es la que menos elementos tiene.

Comment: Hola Sergio. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Si miras [ask] verás que una parte importante es mostrar lo que has intentado. Eso nos contextualiza en tu codigo y podemos decirte qué tienes mal y cómo mejorarlo. Muestranoslo y dinos por qué eso que probaste ha fallado: errores, resultado no esperado, otros problemas? Un saludo

Comment: Lo que he intentado a sido ir recorriendo todo el diccionario con un foreach y guardar el valor que menos elementos tiene, pero no me funciona muy bien y seguro que hay alguna forma que con una simple consulta no haga falta utilizar un foreach

Comment: aunque la simple consulta sea Linq, aunque no lo creas, solo estas ofuscando un for each (que es lo que hace internamente) y como es que no te funciona muy bien?? porque no muestras ese codigo? y nos cuentas que parte no funciona bien?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una solucion muy sencilla usando el método de Linq [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx). Simplemente,ordena tu lista por el numero de elementos del `Value` y devuelve el primero:

```
var resultado = _listInfo.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Count).First().Key;
```

Debes tener en cuenta que si la colección no tiene elementos este código dará una excepción, asi que debes controlar esta posibilidad o usar `FirstOrDefault` en lugar de `First`, lo que devolverá `null` en caso de que la colección esté vacía.

---

Como demostración de que en programación siempre hay varias formas de hacer una misma cosa, te pongo otra solución usando los métodos `Where` y `Min`:

```
var resultado = _listInfo.Where(x => x.Value.Count == _listInfo.Min(y => y.Value.Count))
                         .FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

---

Por último, una solución "clasica" con un bucle:

```
int numElementosMenor=int.MaxValue;
string keyDelMenor = "";
foreach(var v in _listInfo)
{
    int numelementos = v.Value.Count;
    if (numelementos < numElementosMenor)
    {
        keyDelMenor = v.Key;
        numElementosMenor = numelementos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era lo que buscaba!